# Inline styling not being read via Email SQL

Tags: html, css, sql

I have a query that retrieves certain columns and sends an email out which works fine.

However, in the columns, there are in line styling (ex. p style="font-family:arial, font-size:15px"). When the email is sent, the styling that is present in the column are not being seen in the email.

My question is: How can I get the inline styling to appear when the email is sent out?

Comment: You mean, you can't see these styles working in the Email or you simply can't see these inline styles present there?

Comment: @RajanBenipuri I can not see the styling working in the email. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: which email client (Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook etc.) you are sending emails to?

Comment: @RajanBenipuri: The data was sent to Outlook

Answer (score 0):

Not all Email clients support all style tags. Its best to wrap your email template in `<table></table>` and try to add CSS tags supported by most of the email clients.

To get more info about CSS Support Guide for Email Clients [check this link.](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Comment: @ RajanBenipuri: The thing I am wrapping the email template in table tags. However, the user is able to add their own styling and it is stored in the database. and the link that was provided, it appears that inline styling is possible in the body

Comment: Check the link in my answer. You will get a list of all the supported CSS rules by all major email clients.

Comment: @ RajanBenpuri: According to the link you provided in your answer, it is possible. If so, I am not able to get the email to render the styling

Comment: As far as I can see, Outlook doesn't support most of the Style Rules.

Comment: @ RajanBenipuri: I see. Thank you for you help